# how to implement voip in my react native app?

Tags: react-native, webrtc, voip

We want to implement VOIP Uber has built in our react native app we are building, what is the best way to do it ? Is there any libraries that I can use instead of building from scratch ?

Answer (score 0):

If its simple just one to one VOIP then use `react-native-webrtc` on your react-native application plus your webrtc use `simple-peer` which is a nice and simple wrapper around `webrtc`